# How do I retrieve the label information from a Plotly scatterplot, of only samples(points) in the plot I have highlighted with lasso or zoom

Tags: python, plot, plotly

How do I retrieve the label information from a Plotly scatterplot, of only samples(points) in the plot I have highlighted with lasso or zoom?

for example

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length",
                 color="species",size='petal_length',
                 hover_data=['petal_width'])


fig.show()
```

makes the plots below

[image: full plot]

and I want to retrieve the labels or coordinates of the highlighted samples in the plot below

[image: highlighted plot]